# Plotting geom_vline() in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a reactive dataframe `x()` which essentially filters a dataframe based on `radioButtons()`

```
x <- reactive({
  if(input$sex=='Both')
    dataSet <- patients
  else dataSet <- patients %>% filter(gender==input$sex)
  dataSet
})
```

I am then rendering a plot which displays a histogram based on a `selectInput()`using the following code:

```
output$histo <- renderPlotly({
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(x(), aes_string(input$varble))+
      geom_histogram(bins=input$bins)+
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(input$varble)),  col='red',size=1, linetype="dashed")+
      theme(legend.position="top")
  )
})
```

While the histogram renders on the ui, `geom_vline()` doesn't. I get this warning:

```
Warning in mean.default(input$varble) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

For the `aes()` argument in `geom_vline()`, I have tried `x()$input$varble` as well as changing `aes` to `aes_`. Both don't seem to work. What am I missing?

Here's some of the data:

```
dput(patients)
structure(list(age = c(25L, 34L, 72L, 66L, 46L, 67L, 46L, 32L, 
27L, 65L), height = c(152, 174, 165, 148, 152, 152, 178, 169, 
179, 166), weight = c(65, 78, 68, 45, 58, 58, 72, 57, 72, 48), 
    gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", 
"height", "weight", "gender"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here's the code for the `selectInput()`:

```
selectInput("varble","Select Variable for Histogram",
                                         choices = c("age","height","weight"))
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data using for example `dput(head(patients))`.

Comment: @GregordeCillia included some data now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `varmean <- mean(x()[[input$variable]])`. Here is a full example

### Data

```
patients <- read.table(text = 
                         "
   age height weight gender
1   25    152     65   Male
2   34    174     78   Male
3   72    165     68   Male
4   66    148     45 Female
5   46    152     58 Female
6   67    152     58 Female
7   46    178     72   Male
8   32    169     57   Male
9   27    179     72   Male
10  65    166     48   Male")
```

### App

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("variable", "Select variable for the histogram",
                choices = names(patients)[1:3]),
    selectInput("sex", "Choose a gender", c(levels(patients$gender), "Both")),
    plotlyOutput("histo")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    x <- reactive({
      if(req(input$sex) == 'Both')
        patients
      else 
        patients %>% filter(gender == input$sex)
    })

    output$histo <- renderPlotly({
      x <- req(x())
      varmean <- mean(x[[input$variable]])

      ggplot(x, aes_string(input$variable)) +
        geom_histogram(bins = input$bins) +
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = varmean), 
                   col = 'red', size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
        theme(legend.position = "top")
    })
  }
)
```

Alternatively, you could use `aes(xintercept = mean(get(input$variable)))`

Comment: Thanks, `aes(xintercept = mean(get(input$variable)))` works too.

Comment: Glad I could help!